# LTE connection for Desktop

Tags: internet, pci, wan

I have been searching in Internet about how to connect to a LTE connection. I want to use cellular LTE internet in my desktop. There is no WWAN card for desktop also. So my question is how to use LTE internet in my desktop without a dongle or a LTE router. Perhaps a WWAN or a LTE card that supports SIM in PCI X1.

Comment: You will need a PCIe to Mini PCI card with SIM slot, then you can shop for an LTE card. Otherwise you can pick up one of these: https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Express-Converter-Support-Wireless/dp/B07FJXNLLT

Answer (score 0):

**You are looking for a Mini PCI-E to PCI-E 1x adapter with sim card slot.**

Those cards can be found on several locations online. But if you are looking for a LTE backup connection for your home internet, you should consider adressing this on the router level, either through a USB dongle or integrated on a motherboard that you run router software on.

Answer (score 0):

Without any router, you must have a wireless card in your desktop computer.

I have a HUAWEI LTE E8372 cellular modem and I have a Wireless card (installed it in a card slot) in my computer and the cellular internet works fine with both Desktop and Laptop.

If you do not want to put a wireless card in your desktop (no issues in my computer), then you need a Router that can support the device you have. My router does not support my device.

So:  Either wireless card in Desktop computer, or, Router to support cellular device.